# How to make a linux script its output to a new text file from within the script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a script `getInfo.sh` I made in Linux that collects information about the user, date, number of users logged into current environment, and many other features.

I could easily outside of the file have something where it is `./getInfo.sh > results.txt`.

However I would like this to happen automatically within the script.

If I were to include the `./getInfo.sh > results.txt` within the script itself it would create an infinite loop as each time it hits the `./getInfo.sh` it will re-run the script and create an infinite loop.

Any alternatives here?

Comment: Add `exec 2>&1>results.txt &` as the first command in your script.

Comment: Or, just redirect each of the outputs of the script to your new file, e.g. `echo "something important" >> newfile` - you can pass the output file as a parameter or write to a default name if no argument is provided.

Comment: Correcting my previous comment: add `exec 2>&1>& results.txt` as the first command in your script. That will redirect all output (errors included), to `results.txt`. If you want errors messages still be printed to console, use this instead `exec 1>& results.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output everythig including errors, put this as the first command in your script:

```
exec 2>&1>& results.txt
```

If you want don't want the errors to be in the file and instead have them outputted to the console, then add this as the first command in your script:

```
exec 1>& results.txt
```

---

Some extras...

If you want to have the everything **not including errors** outputted to a file and shown in the console, then add this as the first command in your script:

```
exec > >(tee -ia results.txt)
```

If you want also want the errors outputted to a file and shown in the console, then add the command shown above and this command to the start of your script:

```
exec 2> >(tee -ia errors.txt)
```

---

Credits to [@accdias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6789321/accdias) for the first solution

Credits to [@Paused until further notice.](https://superuser.com/users/310/paused-until-further-notice) for the second solution: https://superuser.com/a/86955/1040587